# Jenkins nuget restore downloading wrong/old nuget package

Tags: jenkins, nexus, nuget-package-restore

Initially the Common.dll was placed at the root of nuget package, later I moved it into the \lib\net35 folder. Now I can see it's right in the Nexus nuget repo, but when Jenkins builds, the one downloaded into the packages folder is not right. I've expired the cache in Nexus, still same error. Below is my command in Jenkins:

```
D:\Nuget\nuget.exe restore githubSuspsendInactiveADAccounts.sln -Source http://invtnexus.pp.com/nexus/service/local/nuget/nuget-group/

[D:\public_jenprodslave_1\workspace\DevOps\AdminTasks\GitHub-SuspendInactiveADAccounts\githubSuspsendInactiveADAccounts\githubSuspsendInactiveADAccounts.csproj]
          For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}".
          Considered "..\packages\Common.1.1.0.0\lib\net35\Common.dll", but it didn't exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade from v2.8 to the latest 3.4 resolved this issue, or add "-nocache" to the nuget restore command.